# Is there a way to clear the DHCP leases for personal hotspot on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, dhcp

Is there a programmatic way to clear the DHCP leases on personal hotspot ?

By default Apple lets you provide 13 DHCP leases on hotspot, each lease is held for 24 hours.  This is not about concurrent clients but how many clients can request a lease in 24 hrs.

Turning on/off WiFi hotspot or devices does not clear these leases. Is there a legitimate programmatic call to clear the lease table ?

Answer (score 1):

Apple responded that there is no API to write to any of the personal hotspot settings :(